# Oracle Exception: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am developing web application using JSP and Servlet (IDE: Eclipse, Container: Tomcat7.0, DB: Oracle 10)

I want to get data from two table in a single query

**Query:**

```
query = "select * from PROTOCOL as a, ACTIONS as b where a.PROTOCOL_ID = b.PROTOCOL_ID";
```

But after running the application I am getting the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

is there anything wrong in query?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem you have is keyword `AS`. This is used for columns in `SELECT` section. It is not valid for `FROM` where you specify the tables.

You have

`select * from PROTOCOL as a, ACTIONS as b`

should be

`select * from PROTOCOL a, ACTIONS b...`

From [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#sthref9806)

> **t_alias**
>
> Specify a correlation name, which is alias for the table, view,
>   materialized view, or subquery for evaluating the query. This alias is
>   required if the select list references any object type attributes or
>   object type methods. Correlation names are most often used in a
>   correlated query. Other references to the table, view, or materialized
>   view throughout the query must refer to this alias.

**Example:**

```
SELECT select_list 
    FROM table1 t_alias1 
    WHERE expr operator 
        (SELECT column_list 
            FROM table2 t_alias2 
            WHERE t_alias1.column 
               operator t_alias2.column);
```

Comment: @gdoron, Yeap. That is common. But in Oracle [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm#sthref3167) using as is not allowed there.

Comment: @Bhushan so does PROTOCOL and ACTIONS exist and are they visible to the user who is querying them (additionally, if you're not logging on as the table owner, ensure a synonym exists or you'll have to prefix with the owner name)?

Comment: @Vash, not sure where you seen there anything about alias or `as` grammer.

Comment: @gdoron, I have added the doc to answer. You will not find anything about `As` there because it is not allowed.

Comment: @Bhushan,  On SO (StackOverflow) we have rule one problem one question. The ORA-00942 means that you do not have access to that table or it does not exists.

Comment: @Vash, so what exactly the docs you added adds(?!) anyway, I saw it's allowed tomorrow at work I'll check the `AS`, I admit I never used it...

Comment: The description of t_alias. Good luck tomorrow then ;-).

Answer (score 2):

wrong alias syntax. try the following:

```
query = "select * from PROTOCOL a,ACTIONS b where a.PROTOCOL_ID = b.PROTOCOL_ID";
```

Comment: that is because the PROTOCOL or ACTIONS table does not exist, or in a different schema, on which you do not have any grants. check the table name is correct first, if so, find the details from all_objects/dba_objects view. check the object_name,object_type & owner.

if the owner is say apps change the query with APPS.PROTOCOL & APPS.ACTIONS

Answer (score 0):

A comment here for anyone may need it.. PostgreSQL seems to accept AS next to FROM/JOIN